# Illustrator - Make paths as a compound path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, path, pathfinder

I am having a simple issue from import SVG path to [Fontello](http://fontello.com/):

`'id.svg' contains multiple paths/shapes. Please, make them a compound path, and try import again.`

So, I have this vector:

[image: Paths to SVG]

### What I really tried:

**1)** Search on Google **!**
**2)** Unite paths in *Pathfinder*
**3)** Join Paths in `Object > Path > Join`

---

### The Results

**1)** Teach me other 2 options, none of them works   **-->** Actually bring me to some kind of *Fontello*'s forum, 2 unanswered posts.
**2)** Only group paths (once them don't touch each other)
**3)** Nothing happened.

Is there anybody that already tried to import SVG icons to *Fontello*?

Comment: Why SVG? will other formats will work for you?

Comment: @FerdiÇıldız Hmmm... My question is something like: _I CAN'T IMPORT  **SVG** ICON TO FONTELLO._ (...) :)

Comment: I think it would be a good alternative, check this out: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/font-awesome-as-photoshop-custom-shape-set

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To create compound paths/shapes, you simply need to select the objects then choose `Object > Compound Path > Make` from the menu.

Comment: Which tool do you use for this menu option?

Comment: @RogerW ... as the question is tagged... Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Okay thanks, missed the tag in the title.