# How to use ionicons in photoshop like font awesome?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, fonts

Can we use [ionicons](https://ionicons.com/) like we use `font awesome`? or is there any workaround. Currently, they have the option to download SVG's but they are not opening in photoshop for me (I am using cs6).

Comment: Do [these answers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/font-awesome-as-photoshop-custom-shape-set/27281#27281) begin to answer your question?

Comment: How do we use font awesome in PS cs 6? I have no recollection of what the svg support was pre CC. I could've sworn you could open svg's but PS would rasterize them... But I guess not? — I personally use [IconJar](https://geticonjar.com/) (Mac only). You can drag icons from IconJar to the application... but that is no different than dragging/opening .svg files in PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't open an SVG in Photoshop - that will rasterize it. In some instances I've found that Photoshop can have problems rasterizing an SVG, especially a complex one.

Instead try placing the SVG using *File > Place linked/embedded*, or drag and drop the file into an existing document, where it will be converted into a Smart Object, and will remain a vector image. This certainly works in Photoshop CC. I don't have a copy of CS6 to test it.

If this still causes problems, perhaps try opening the SVG in Illustrator, and save as an AI file, then place the AI file as a Smart Object in a Photoshop document.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing the same. Open in illustrator and then drag into photoshop as a smart object. Not an efficient solution like font-awesome we use but it works. thanks

Comment: @AamirShahzad, you still haven't told us how you use font awesome in cs6. Dude, cs6/cc was released like 8 years ago. I can't remember further than 24hours you think I remember how things worked I cs6? :) Like I think I maybe had an extension for fontawesome. But if you use it as a font, you could probably use like iconmoon.io to convert any icon pack into a font... though I'm not s sure that would make it any easier than just converting the files to png once and just dragging them in on demand..

Comment: @Joonas this is how you use font awesome. https://knackforge.com/blog/manoj/how-use-font-awesome-icons-adobe-photoshop

Comment: Yea, svg's converted into a font using iconmoon would work the same way.